# Using loop inside a functional component for a string

Tags: reactjs, sass, jsx, react-functional-component

I am trying to create a box dynamically for the number of words in a string in a functional component.

```
import React from "react";

import "./guessBox.styles.scss";

const Guessbox = ({  wordLength }) => {
    let counter = wordLength
  return (
       <div className='guess-box-container'>
           {while(counter >0)(
               <div className='word-box'></div>
               {counter = counter -1}
           ) }

       </div>
    }
  );
};

export default Guessbox;
```

But I get the following error on the process.

```
./src/Components/guessBox/guessBox.component.jsx
  Line 9:13:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   7 |   return (
   8 |        <div className='guess-box-container'>
>  9 |            {while(counter >0)(
     |             ^
  10 |                <div className='word-box'></div>
  11 |                {counter = counter -1}
  12 |            ) }
```

What is the correct way to loop inside a functional component?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I suggestion is to loop through an array map

```
import React from "react";

import "./guessBox.styles.scss";

const Guessbox = ({  wordLength }) => {

  const words = ["Your","Word","List"] // you have have a complex any complex object arrays based on your data and needs;
  
  return (
       <div className='guess-box-container'>
         {words.map((word,index)=>{
          return <renderWordBox word={word}  />
         })}
       </div> 
  )



const renderWordBox = (word) => {
  return  <div className='word-box'>{word}</div>
}

export default Guessbox;
```

Based on your code

```
import React from "react";

import "./guessBox.styles.scss";

const Guessbox = ({  wordLength }) => {
    let counter = wordLength
  return (
       <div className='guess-box-container'>
          {renderBox(counter)}    
       </div> 
    }
  );
};


const renderBox = (counter) => {
  while (counter > 0) {
    counter = counter -1
    return  <div key={counter} className='word-box'/>
  }
}

export default Guessbox;
```

using a For loop

```
const renderBox = (counter) => {
  for (i = 0; i <counter ; i++) {
   return  <div key={i} className='word-box'/>
  }
}
```